# Issue executing Notepad.exe from windows Service on windows7

Tags: c++, windows-services

I have created the windows service which does the ShellExecute command on noteapad.exe.
When service is installed the notepad.exe is executed and only seen in task manager. The Notepad.exe window is not visible. 
Could anyone let me know what may be the issue with this, I have tried this on Windows XP where it works fine.

Following is the code for ShellExecute

```
::ShellExecute(NULL,
        NULL,
        _T("notepad.exe"),
        _T("C:\\Users\\testuser\\Desktop\\review_comments.txt"),
        _T("C:\\Windows\\System32"),
        SW_SHOWMAXIMIZED);
```

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2):

Starting from Vista and Windows Server 2003 a service is no longer allowed to show a window. 
(And the executed notepad still is owned by the service...)

hth

Mario

Comment: So what should be done .. If I want to execute an application from windows service

Comment: in the windows service settings there is a checkbox: allow desktop interaction. Try to enable this.

Comment: I wanted to do something similar a while ago, but I did not find a way... I resorted to start my program via Autostart and let it run as a system-tray program...

Comment: Also checking the allow desktop interaction. but it did not work.

Comment: Can you try to show a message box from within your service? Again, I had the same issue a while back and was not able to solve it. Some google'ing showed that most applications that do this kind of work resort to a second app that runs in the system tray started via startup...